# Using .addClass on data-attribute elements with specific values

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, popup

I'm trying to create a modal popup system in jQuery, that keeps the code as simple as possible. I've looked up tutorials on this, but they all only ever show it working with one modal in the HTML. If I have multiple modals on the page with the attribute data-popup, how can I make only the one selected popup?

Here's my current attempt:

```
$("[data-popupBtn]").click(function() {
  if ($("[data-popupBtn='schedule']")) {
    $("[data-popup='schedule']").addClass("visible");
    $(".popup-bg").addClass("visible");
  } else {
    if ($("[data-popupBtn='booklet']")) {
      $("[data-popup='booklet']").addClass("visible");
      $(".popup-bg").addClass("visible");
    } else {
      null
    }
  }
})
```

With the HTML being:

```
<div class="popup-bg">

  <div class="popup" data-popup="schedule">
    <a class="popup-x">&times;</a>
    <div>
      <p>CONTENT</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="popup" data-popup="booklet">
    <a class="popup-x">&times;</a>
    <div>
      <p>CONTENT</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

My goal in this was to create triggers that can be used anywhere on the page, as many times as I want with a simple `data-popupBtn="insertPopupType"` in the element. The code I currently have works flawlessly for making the `data-popup="schedule"` popup... but the jQuery seems to fail when checking the `if ($("[data-popupBtn='schedule']"))` vs the `if ($("[data-popupBtn='booklet']"))`. If you have a better way of incorporating multiple modal popups on a single page, let me know.

Comment: Unclear how you can click on a "popup" that is not "visible"... But for sure, the condition `if ($("[data-popupBtn='schedule']"))` will always be `true` if the element exist in the page. -- Maybe you will be interested in jQuery [.is()](https://api.jquery.com/is/) and make a condition like `if ($(this).is($("[data-popupBtn='schedule']"))`. Try it and if you still have problems, please make sure you provide everything to reproduce the issue.

Comment: That's exactly what it was missing! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Louys Patrice Bessette answered my question in a comment! Thanks!

"Unclear how you can click on a "popup" that is not "visible"... But for sure, the condition `if ($("[data-popupBtn='schedule']"))` will always be `true` if the element exist in the page. -- Maybe you will be interested in jQuery .is() and make a condition like `if ($(this).is($("[data-popupBtn='schedule']"))`. Try it and if you still have problems, please make sure you provide everything to reproduce the issue." – Louys Patrice Bessette Dec 10 at 17:54

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class="btn" data-popup="schedule">Button for Schedule</a>
<a class="btn" data-popup="schedule">Button for Schedule</a>
<div class="popup-bg">

 <div class="popup" data-popup="schedule">
   <a class="popup-x">&times;</a>
  <div>
  <p>CONTENT Schedule</p>
</div>
</div>


<div class="popup" data-popup="booklet">
<a class="popup-x">&times;</a>
<div>
  <p>CONTENT</p>
</div>
</div>

</div>
$("[data-popup]").click(function() {
$(".popup-bg").addClass("visible");
$('[data-popup='+$(this).data('popup')+']').addClass('visible')

})
```